# Azure data bricks external hive metastore creation

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, hive-metastore

I am creating a metastore in azure databricks for azure sql.I have given below commands to cluster config using 7.3 runtime. As mentioned in the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore#spark-options

```
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=hivemetastore
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName xxxx
datanucleus.fixedDatastore false
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword xxxx
datanucleus.autoCreateSchema true
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars builtin
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version 1.2.1
hive.metastore.schema.verification.record.version false 
hive.metastore.schema.verification false
```

--

After this when I tried to create database metastore I will get cancelled automatically.
Error I am getting in Data section in databricks which I am not able to copy also.

[image]

Cluster setting
[image]

Command

[image]

Comment: you need to check driver logs, also check the firewall

Comment: Hello Alex Firewall of sql server I already added my ip. Is there any thing I can check.

Comment: you need to add IPs of all nodes in the cluster. Please post driver logs

Comment: HiveConf: Found configuration file file:/databricks/hive/conf/hive-site.xml
SessionState: Created HDFS directory:/tmp/hive/root/86-43-7590b1
SessionState: Created local directory:/local_disk0/tmp/root/89a4-4243-8633-7747450590b1
SessionState: Created HDFS directory:/tmp/hive/root/86b-4243-863390b1/_tmp_space.db
HiveClientImpl: Warehouse location for Hive client(version 2.3.7) is /user/hive/warehouse
Hive: Databricks: invoke reloadFunctions call during init.
HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.jdbc.timeout does not exist
HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.retries.wait does not exist

Comment: Hello
 I can able to connect to sql server. I can see some tables like dbo.database_params,dbo.dbs,dbo.roles and many more are created. But when I try to create a simple table in databricks from csv. I am getting a error org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:An exception was thrown while adding/validating class(es) : The size (32672) given to the column 'PARAM_VALUE' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000). –

Answer (score 0):

**--Update**

According to the error message updated in the comments

The maximum length allowed is 8000, when the the length specified in declaring a VARCHAR column.

**WorkAround:** Use either VARCHAR(8000) or VARCHAR(MAX) for column 'PARAM_VALUE'. I would prefer using nvarchar(max), cause an **nvarchar (MAX)** can store up to 2GB of characters.

---

Apparently found an official record of the know issue!

See [Error in CREATE TABLE with external Hive metastore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/metastore/create-table-error-external-hive)

> This is a known issue with MySQL 8.0 when the default charset is
> utfmb4.

Try running this to confirm

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S WHERE schema_name = "<database-name>"
```

If yes, Refer [Solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/metastore/create-table-error-external-hive#solution)

> You need to update or recreate the database and set the charset to
> latin1.

You have 2 options:

1. Manually run create statements in the Hive database with DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 at the end of each CREATE TABLE statement.
2. Setup the database and user accounts. And create the database and run alter database hive character set latin1; before you launch the metastore. (This command sets the default CHARSET for the database. It is applied when the metastore creates tables.)

Comment: No I am using till jdbc:sqlserver://externalhive.database.windows.net:1433;database=xyz

Comment: Can you try the complete string from portal as is

Comment: Tried already but no luck

Comment: I have changed the hive version 1.2.1 to Hive 2.3.7 (Databricks Runtime 7.0 and above): & already done set spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars to builtin.

Comment: I have added below library still I want to follow the jars it is difficult to understand and having only one article.
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars builtin
hive.metastore.schema.verification false
datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables true
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version 2.3.7

Comment: there is a similar issue mentioned in the troubleshooting section of same doc, try check as updated

Comment: Hello Karthik I can able to connect to sql server. I can see some tables like dbo.database_params,dbo.dbs,dbo.roles and many more are created. But when I try to create a simple table in databricks from csv. I am getting a error org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:An exception was thrown while adding/validating class(es) : The size (32672) given to the column 'PARAM_VALUE' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).

Comment: Please check the updated details and workaround!

Comment: Nope it doesn't help I done it from my self. I have to choose the jar 0.13 for cluster 7.3. I am using azure sql not mysql.